# SQL Server delete or select and delete

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-delete

I have table with about 50k rows.

On some user request I should check if database contains some data and remove that. Just 1% of request requires delete so.

Should I execute select and then in 1% cases execute delete or immediately execute delete?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean: why not just `DELETE` directly? If no rows are affected then the data you wanted to delete doesn't exist anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to ask, but here is what I do when I want to delete records.

```
select *
from MyTable
where --all my conditions
```

Then, after making sure that the result set is exactly what I want to delete, I do this:

```
--select *
delete from MyTable
where --all my conditions
```

Comment: why you dont execute
delete from MyTable
where --all my conditions without select?